# Bad route appended to URL when redirecting from http to https

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, https

I have a WordPress site hosted on OVH and I'm having issues when redirecting from http to https.

`http://www.example.com` redirects nicely to `https://www.example.com`

`https://www.example.com` redirects nicely to `https://example.com`

However `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com/www`.

I don't know where this extra www is coming from.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: if `https://www.example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` then that can't be your only redirect rule.  That rule only redirects for `http` (no `s`).

Comment: And that rule only redirects to the same _hostname_ anyway (so it couldn't redirect from `www.example.com` to `example.com` even if it was processed). Maybe the redirect is being performed by the application itself? There would seem to be more about your system than what you've posted here. There is nothing here that would redirect from `/` to `/www` either? Check the network traffic in the browser... exactly what redirects and HTTP status codes are you seeing? And clear your browser cache to be sure you aren't seeing a cached redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. There was another redirect I didn't know about, for www to no www, set up in the hosting control panel. And the /www redirect has stopped all of a sudden so may have been a cached redirect after all.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses. There was another redirect I didn't know about, for www to no www, set up in the hosting provider (OVH) control panel. And the /www redirect has stopped all of a sudden so may have been a cached redirect after all.